# mvc wcf security

Tags: wcf, model-view-controller, authentication, wcf-security

I have a MVC application which uses forms authentication. This application also hosts a WCF webservice (the Model). Webservice caters c# objects to the application, and same data is available as JSON when called from outside the application (browser).
Everything is working fine apart from the fact that the Webservice is not authenticating any request. Following is the what I have in web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJson" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="Services.MyService">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:1234/MyService.svc/" binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJson"
              contract="Services.IService"
              behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

I would like to authenticate Webservice requests:

- Requests from within the application should be authenticated automatically
- When Webservice is called from outside the application, users are asked to get authenticated.

Any help would be appreciated.

/D

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an internal endpoint that serves a wsdl for the binding in to the website (authenticated using the ASP.NET identity the website is running under) and a separate binding externally for the JSON requests that uses something like OAuth to authenticate.

Either way you're looking at two different authentication mechanisms.